# Using Popup control in Window 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

> Is there any property of pop up , wherein we can dim the window app.
>   As in metro app there is no Child Window control available , so using
>   popup in place of it but the problem in popup is when it is open the
>   user can still interact with other control on window app.

```
So is there an workaround to make the window app dim when pop is open.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what your trying to do. You can put a Border as first child of the popup which exposes the Background property. So if you specify a not null Background (Transparent for instance) the popup will catch every interactions.

Comment: when i open the popup , i dont want user to interact with rest of the controls present on the app window , want to make the same behavior like an CHildWindow.

Comment: Yes, you just have to make a transparent (transparent background and not null) that takes all the screen and position your childcontrol Inside that popup. The popup will handle every keyboard, mouse and touch events. Just make you have the property IsLightDismissedEnable set to false on the popup.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [MessageDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) class. The popup is meant to be non-modal, letting the user close it by just clicking away from it. The MessageDialog is a regular modal popup that does not let the user interact with the rest of the app when it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on using the popup control, here is a simple workaround:

Make the popup use all the screen (using a grid or border), then set that background to Black with opacity 0.1 (or any other color you see fit, this is to give a "dim" effect), then inside this popup, place another container with the size and margins that you want to act as your "real" popup.

Because the popup takes the whole screen it will prevent the user from clicking anywhere in the screen.